# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, and suppose that $G$ acts by multiplication over the set $X:=G/H$ of the left-hand side classes of $H$ over $G$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions

This action is transitive. Now let be $yH \in X$. What is the kernel of this action?

*I'm afraid that my answer isn't right. Could you check if the KERNEL is exactly this?*

**MY ANSWER:**

Let $A:G \times X \rightarrow [G:H]=X$ be the action mentioned and $\lambda:G\rightarrow \operatorname{Sym}(G)$ (this homomorphism exists because of the permutational representation).
So, we have

$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{ker}(A)&=\{(g,yH) \in A: A(g, yH)=gyH=yH, \forall (g, yH)\}\\
&=\{g \in G: gyH=yH, \forall g \in G\}\\
&=yHy^{-1}, \forall g \in G\; \text{the reason of this step is going to be explained below**}\\
&=\displaystyle\bigcap_{g \in G} yHy^{-1}
\end{align*}
$

Explanation about **:

$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Stab}(yH)&=\{g \in G: gyH=yH\}\\
&=\{g \in G: y^{-1} gyH=H\}\\
&=\{g \in G: y^{-1}gy \in H\}\\
&=\{g \in G: g \in yHy^{-1}\}\\
&=yHy^{-1}
\end{align*}
$

Comment: I think you meant $X:=G/H$, since $[G:H]$ usually denotes the index of $H$ in $G$, so it's a positive integer number, not a set.

Comment: Yes! exactly @user750041 thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if we are given an action of a group $G$ on a set $X$, $G\times X\to X$, we can establish a homomorphism $\lambda\colon G \to \operatorname{Sym}(X)$ by defining $\lambda_g(x):=g\cdot x$. In fact, $\forall g,h\in G,\forall x\in X$:

$$\lambda_{gh}(x)=(gh)\cdot x=g\cdot(h\cdot x)=\lambda_g(\lambda_h(x))=(\lambda_g\lambda_h)(x)$$

whence:

$$\lambda_{gh}=\lambda_g\lambda_h, \space\forall g,h\in G \tag 1$$

(That indeed $\lambda_g \in \operatorname{Sym}(X), \forall g \in G$, also follows from action's axioms.)

The kernel of this homomorphism (the so-called "kernel of the action") is given by:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{ker}\lambda &= \{g\in G\mid\lambda_g=\iota_X\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid\lambda_g(x)=\iota_X(x), \forall x \in X\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid g\cdot x=x, \forall x \in X\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid g\in \operatorname{Stab}(x), \forall x \in X\} \\
&= \{g\in \operatorname{Stab}(x), \forall x \in X\} \\
&= \bigcap_{x\in X}\operatorname{Stab}(x) \\
\tag 2
\end{alignat}

In your case, $X=\{gH, g\in G\}$ and $\operatorname{Stab}(gH)=\{g'\in G\mid g'gH=gH\}$.

**Lemma**. $\operatorname{Stab}(gH)=gHg^{-1}$.

*Proof*.

\begin{alignat}{1}
g'\in \operatorname{Stab}(gH) &\Rightarrow \exists h,h'\in H\mid g'gh=gh' \\
&\Rightarrow \exists h,h'\in H\mid g'=gh'(gh)^{-1}=gh'h^{-1}g^{-1} \\
&\Rightarrow \exists h''\in H\mid g'=gh''g^{-1} \\
&\Rightarrow g'\in gHg^{-1} \\
\end{alignat}

and thence $\operatorname{Stab}(gH)\subseteq gHg^{-1}$. Viceversa:

\begin{alignat}{1}
g'\in gHg^{-1} &\Rightarrow g'g \in gH \\
&\Rightarrow g'gH\subseteq gH \\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

Now:

\begin{alignat}{1}
gH\subseteq g'gH &\iff \forall h \in H, \exists h'\in H\mid gh=g'gh' \\
&\iff \forall h \in H, \exists h'\in H\mid gh=(gh''g^{-1})gh'=gh''h' \\
&\iff h'=(gh'')^{-1}gh=h''^{-1}g^{-1}gh=h''^{-1}h \\
\end{alignat}

Since $h''$ exists by hypothesis ("*Viceversa...*"), such a $h'$ exists, and then indeed:

$$gH\subseteq g'gH \tag 4$$

Therefore, $g'\in gHg^{-1} \Rightarrow g'gH=gH \Rightarrow g'\in \operatorname{Stab}(gH) \Rightarrow gHg^{-1}\subseteq \operatorname{Stab}(gH)$.

$\Box$

By $(2)$ and the Lemma, we have finally:

$$\operatorname{\ker}\lambda = \bigcap_{gH\in G/H}\operatorname{Stab}(gH)= \bigcap_{g\in G}\operatorname{Stab}(gH)=\bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1} \tag 5$$

Comment: Terrific! You're very good at teaching. Thank you!

Comment: The little I know, I try. Thanks

Comment: I'm struggling with the same doubt as other user in this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3648819/groups-of-order-pq-p-and-q-primes-with-pq 

But in my case I didn't understand the following steps:

1) Why is $G/C_{G}(P) \cong Aut (\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ ?
2) How to show that $C_{S_q}(Q)=Q$?
3) Why PQ is not abelian?

I think you can try to answer there. If you want to, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The kernel of $\lambda$ should be $\bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$.
This is called the *normal core* of $H$.

I think this is what you want.  $A$ doesn't have a kernel, as $X$ is only a set.  But $\operatorname{Sym}X$ is a group, and $\lambda$ a homomorphism.  So we can talk about $\operatorname{ker}\lambda:=\{g\in G:\lambda(g)=e\}$.

Comment: Thanks. Is exactly this.

Comment: how did you find $\operatorname{ker}(\lambda)=\displaystyle\bigcap_{g \in G}gHg^{-1}$?

Comment: See this "Group acts on left coset space of subgroup by left multiplication - Groupprops" https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_acts_on_left_coset_space_of_subgroup_by_left_multiplication