# Groups of order $pq$, $p$ and $q$ primes with $p<q$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

**RIGHT ANSWER BY DUMMIT:**
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eujvW.png)

Suppose $|G|=pq$ for primes $p$ and $q$ with $p<q$. Let $P \in Syl_{p}(G)$ and let $Q \in Syl_{q}(G)$. We are going to show that $Q$ is normal in $G$ and if $P$ also normal in $G$, then $G$ is cyclic.

Now the three conditions: $n_q=1+kq$ for some $k\geq 0$, $n_q$ divides $p$ and $p<q$, together force $k=0$. Since $n_q=1$, $Q\trianglelefteq G$.

Since $n_p$ divides the prime $q$, the only possibilities are $n_p=1$ or $q$. In particular, if $p\nmid (q-1)$, then $n_p$ cannot equal $q$, so $P\trianglelefteq G$.

Let $P=\langle x \rangle$ and $Q=\langle y \rangle$. If $P\trianglelefteq G$, then since $G/C_{G}(P)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and the latter group has order $p-1$, Lagrange's Theorem together with the observation that neither $p$ or $q$ can divide $p-1$ implies that $G=C_{G}(P)$. In this case $x \in P \leq Z(G)$ so $x$ and $y$ commute. ($G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{pq}$).

If $p| (q-1)$, we shall see in other chapter that there is a unique non-abelian group of order $pq$ (in which, necessarily, $n_p=q$). We can prove the existence of this group now. Let $Q$ be a Sylow $q-\operatorname{subgroup}$ of the symmetric group of degree $q$ in $S_q$. By Exercise 34 in section 3, ${\color{red}{|N_{S_q}(Q)|=q(q-1)}}$. By assumption, $p|(q-1)$ so by Cauchy's Theorem $N_{S_q}(Q)$ has a subgroup, $P$, of order $p$. By Corollary 15 in Section 3.2, $PQ$ is a group of order $pq$. Since ${\color{red}{C_{S_q}(Q)=(Q)}}$, $PQ$ is a non-abelian group.

MY QUESTIONS ARE IN COLOR ${\color{red}{\text{RED}}}$.

**Can someone provide a step by step answer for the following questions, please?**

1. ${\color{red}{|N_{S_q}(Q)|=q(q-1)}}$ I've done the exercise 34 suggested. However I still not understanding this equality, how to calculate this?
2. ${\color{red}{C_{S_q}(Q)=(Q)}}$ Although I've tried to understand the corollary mentioned I didn't understand this equality in this case!

Comment: Exercise 34 in section 3 is "Prove that if $p$ is a prime and $P$ is a subgroup of $S_p$ of order $p$, then $|N_{S_p}(P)| = p(p-1)$.  [(hint suppressed)]".  Since you have already done this exercise, you already have a step by step answer to your question 1.  So what is it you are asking?

Comment: For me it is not so easy to find that $|N_{S_p}(P)|=p(p-1)$ for instance. Because I need to count the number of p-cycles and I'm struggling with this.

Comment: Why are you counting $p$- (or $q$-)cycles?  Since $q$ is prime, $q$ divides $|S_q|$ and $q^2$ does not.  Consequently any Sylow $q$-subgroup of $S_q$ has order $q$...

Comment: @EricTowers Thank you very much for you attention. I have a question regarding with the item 2 in red: Why can I take $Q$ as a Sylow q−subgroup of the symmetric group of degree $q$ in $S_q$?

Comment: The largest power of $q$ dividing $|S_q|$ is $q^1$, so any Sylow q-subgroup of $S_q$ has order $q$.  Pick one and label it $Q$.  It has degree $q$ because it is necessarily a $q$-cycle, so is a group of permutations of a $q$ element set.  All of the preceding is a consequence of the primeness of $q$.

Answer (score 1):

Dummit has evidently broken it down for you step by step.  Each of your questions in red is answered with an exercise or example.

To summarize, if $p\not|q-1$, then the group is the product of its Sylow subgroups, and is cyclic, isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{pq}$.

If $p|q-1$, there exists a unique nonabelian group of order $pq$.  Note that $C_{S_q}(Q)=Q$ implies that $G$ is nonabelian.  Uniqueness is postponed for the moment.

Comment: Ok, great. About last equality, how to show that $C_{S_q}(Q)=(Q)$? Why can I take $Q$ as a Sylow q−subgroup of the symmetric group of degree $q$ in $S_q$?

Comment: $Q$ embedds into $S_q$ ala Cayley's theorem.