# Prove that a group of order $11 \times 2^{10}$ has a normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I am trying to solve this question:

Prove that a group of order $11 \times 2^{10}$ has a nontrivial proper normal subgroup.

**My trial**

By Sylow theorems I know that $n_2 \in \{1,11\}$ and $n_{11} \in \{1, 2^{10} = 1024\},$ I also know that if either of them were 1, then I am done. Now I want to exclude the case of $n_2 = 11$ and $n_{11} = 1024,$ could someone help me in excluding this case please?

Comment: Any group $G$ will always have the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$ and $G$ itself as normal subgroups. Perhaps, you should replace "normal subgroup" with "**nontrivial proper** normal subgroup".

Comment: Sure you are correct @GeoffreyTrang

Comment: Given that you can assume $n_2=11$ you get a non-trivial homomorphism from your group $G$ to $S_{11}$. But $2^{10}$ is not a factor of $11!$ so the homomorphism cannot be injective. In other words, you don't really need $n_{11}$ at all to conclude.

Comment: I think you are arguing using group actions ..... I was thinking about arguing via counting but I am not quite sure how to count the number of elements in the Sylow $2$- subgroups because I am not sure what is the number of elements in the intersection of them. @JyrkiLahtonen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally, let $G$ be a group of order $p^nq$, for $p$ and $q$ distinct primes (and the integer $n\ge 1$). By Sylow III, $n_p=1$ or $n_p=q$. If $n_p=1$, you are done. Let's then suppose $n_p=q$; the intersection of all the $p$-Sylow subgroups is normal$^\dagger$, so if it is non-trivial, then you are done again. On the other hand, if such intersection is trivial, then there are $p^nq-(p^n-1)q-1=q-1$ non-trivial elements out of the $p$-Sylow subgroups; so, there's no room for more than one $q$-Sylow subgroup, which is then normal. Therefore, in any case $G$ has a non-trivial proper normal subgroup.

---

$^\dagger$By Sylow II ("$G$ acts transitively by conjugation on the set $\operatorname {Syl}_p(G)$"), the intersection of *all* the conjugates of any $P\in\operatorname {Syl}_p(G)$ is equal to the intersection of *all* the $p$-Sylow subgroups. And the former is well-known to be a [normal subgroup of $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4055576/1007416) (irrespective of being $P$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup; this holds for any subgroup).

Comment: I did not get the idea of your solution at all and why if the intersection is non-trivial then it is normal on the third line. I will post another question with the solution I have because I do not understand it as well and hopefully if you are willing to check it please do.

Comment: I've tried to make clearer the point by an edit, @Brain.