# Excluding the case $n_2 = 11$ and $n_{11} = 1024.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Prove that a group of order $11 \times 2^{10}$ has a normal subgroup.

And here is a solution I found to the part of excluding the case $n_2 = 11$ and $n_{11} = 1024.$:

Suppose that $n_2 = 11$ and $n_{11} = 1024.$ Let $\{H_i\}_{i=1}^{2^{10}}$ be the set of all $11$-Sylow subgroups of $G.$ Since $11$ is prime, if $i \neq j,$ then $H_i \cap H_j = \{e\}.$ This implies that $|\cup_{i=1}^{2^{10}}H| = 1 + 10. 2^{10}.$ Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be $2$- Sylow subgroups of $G.$ Since $(2,11) = 1,$ this implies that $K_i \cap H_j = \{e\}.$ Since $K_1$ and $K_2$ are distinct subgroups, $|K_1 \cap K_2| > 1$ which implies $|K_1 \cup K_2| \geq 2^{10} + 1.$ This implies $|K_1 \cup K_2 \cup (\cup_{i=1}^{2^{10}} H_i)| \geq 1 + 10.2^{10} + 2^{10} = 1 + 11. 2^{10} > |G|.$ This is a contradiction.

Still I do not understand the idea of the contradiction, could someone help me understand this solution please?

**Here is what I know so far:**

By Sylow theorems I know that $n_2 \in \{1,11\}$ and $n_{11} \in \{1, 2^{10} = 1024\},$ I also know that if either of them were 1, then I am done. Now I want to exclude the case of $n_2 = 11$ and $n_{11} = 1024.$

**EDIT:**

I am asking about a specific solution here in this question, it is not a duplicate of the suggested one.

Comment: The point is that the $11$-Sylow subgroups use up so many elements (they are pairwise disjoint except for the common element of the identity) that there’s very little room remaining for the $2$-Sylow subgroups.  So little, in fact, that there can only be $1$ of them.

Comment: How can we prove this @RobertShore ? why why the $11$-Sylow subgroups use up so many elements, how did you know that they are pairwise disjoint? could u please explain more details?

Comment: @Brain They are cyclic of prime order, so every non-identity element is a generator. Thus if the intersection of two such subgroups contains a non-identity element, then they must be equal.

Comment: Please do not use pictures to covey information not present otherwise in your post. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742) for why.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am so sorry about that I will edit my post in about 5 hours.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn how did you know from their numbers that they are cyclic of prime orders.... what about the idea used in proving the contradiction in the picture? what is this idea?

Comment: If G is a group of order prime number p, then G is cyclic.

Comment: It’s important that the $11$-Sylow subgroups have prime order ($11$), not prime power order.  The intersection of two Sylow subgroups is itself a subgroup of each Sylow subgroup, but a subgroup of prime order has no non-trivial proper subgroup.  The intersection must be a proper subgroup of each Sylow subgroup, so the only possibility is the trivial subgroup.

Comment: Is this a lecture note? I think the author have used some theorems that they have proved earlier.

Comment: Why did you repost [your question from yesterday?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4449984/11619)

Comment: Because I did not understand the answer there @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Then you could have edited the question, adding details of what is missing. And waited for other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a contradiction is if there are no normal Sylow $11$-subgroup or $2$-subgroup, then the total amount of elements in the group is greater than the order of a group. A clear contradiction.

Fact implicitly used in the proof is Lagrange's theorem (that is how its deduced that $H_i\cap H_J=\{e\}$ and $K_i\cap H_j=\{e\}$). The rest is completely clear.

Comment: why since $11$ is prime, then $H_i \cap H_j = \{e\}$ in the solution I posted?

Comment: Why $|\cup_{i = 1}^{2^{10}}H_i| = 1 + 10 . 2^{10}$ in the solution I posted?

Comment: Well. You see. $H_i\cap H_j$ is a subgroup of $H_i$. What are the possible cases for $| H_i\cap H_j|$? They are $1$ and $11$. Since $H_i\ne H_j$, the case $| H_i\cap H_j|=11$ is not possible. You have $2^{10}$ Sylow $11$-subgroups. We know that they intersect trivially, so there are $2^{10}\cdot(|H|-1)$ non-trivial elements in Sylow $11$-subgroups + the trivial element.

Comment: Is the first line and half in your previous comment is by Lagrange Theorem?

Comment: Yes. Dont wanna be mean, but you have google, right?

Comment: yeah, but I just do not remember

Comment: So the set of all $11$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ does not have to have order $11$? but why we are calling them $11$-subgroups?

Comment: $11$-Sylow subgroup ~ Sylow $11$-subgroup ~ Sylow subgroup of order $11^n$ -- that is just a notation. I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Does not a $p$-group is a group of order $p^n$ for $n\geq 1$? what about the **subgroup** of this $p$-group? its order can be $1 , p, p^2, \dots$ only,  right?

Comment: Does the order of the union of subgroups necessarily the sum of the orders of the subgroups? I think this idea is used here  $|\cup_{i=1}^{2^{10}}H| = 1 + 10. 2^{10}$ .... am I correct?

Comment: Why, in the answer I posted, it is saying that since $K_1$ and $K_2$ are distinct subgroups then $|K_1 \cap K_2| > 1$? more specifically, should $|K_1 \cap K_2| = 2$ or I am missing something?

Comment: Also, how did the author know that $|K_1 \cup K_2| \geq 2^{10} + 1,$ could you please explain this to me?

Comment: should not the intersection of any $2$-Sylow subgroup be the identity?

Comment: In your first comment, I think you meant $|H_i| - 1$ .... right?

Comment: I think you are also using the idea that, in a finite group, the order of an element is the order of the subgroup it lies in and hence the order of an element must divide the order of the big group as well ..... right?