# Let $G$ be a simple group, $H\leq G,[G:H]=n$ Prove $G \cong K,K\leq{\rm Sym}(n)$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-actions, symmetric-groups, simple-groups

> Let $G$ be a simple group, $H\leq G,[G:H]=n$. Prove $G \cong K,K\leq{\rm Sym}(n)$.

Denote an action by $G \curvearrowright G/H$.

This action induces the homomorphism $\rho : G\to{\rm Sym}(G/H)\cong{\rm Sym}(n)$.

Using isomorphism first theorem, $\exists \ker\rho \triangleleft G$ such that $\frac{G}{\ker\rho}\cong {\rm Im}(\rho)\leq{\rm Sym}(n)$.

Since $G$ is simple, $\ker\rho=\{1\},G$.

If $\ker\rho=G$ then $\frac{G}{G}=\{1\}\implies {\rm Im}(\rho)\cong{\rm Sym}(1),$ which implies $H$ is a normal subgroup, contradicting the fact that $G$ is simple. (I am not sure about this explanation.)

Also $$\ker\rho=\{1\}\implies G\cong{\rm Im}(\rho)\leq {\rm Sym}(n)$$ as required.

Is my solution correct?

Any feedback is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Please put punctuation marks *flush* against the lefthand word, like "this," and not "this ,".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the action you're considering,  the kernel *can't* be $G$, if $n\gt1$, because it's equal to $\bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}\subset H$.

$\therefore$ the kernel of $\rho $ is trivial.  And so you have an embedding of $G$ into $S_n$.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not same explanation as mine?

Comment: No.  I think you need to know,  and I assume you mean the left translation action,  that the kernel is what I indicated.   It's called the normal core.  Of course,  if $n=1$, then you can't say anything,  because the kernel is $G$.

Comment: It is the same proof,  I just added something.

Comment: Here's a proof of that fact https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3631336/1070376